# Permute string of Kronecker products

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

A function I am writing will receive as input a matrix H=A x B x I x I, where each matrix is square and of dimension d, the cross refers to the Kronecker product `np.kron` and I is the identity `np.eye(d)`. Thus

```
I = np.eye(d)
H = np.kron(A, B)
H = np.kron(H, I)
H = np.kron(H, I)
```

Given H and the above form, but without knowledge of A and B, I would like to construct G = I x A x I x B  e.g. the result of

```
G = np.kron(I, A)
G = np.kron(G, I)
G = np.kron(G, B)
```

It should be possible to do this by applying some permutation to H. How do I implement that permutation?

Comment: are you familiar with the `vec` operation? You need to solve a linear system not a permutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transposing with (2,0,3,1,6,4,7,5) (after expanding to 8 axes) appears to do it:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>>
>>> A = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))
>>> B = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))
>>> I = np.identity(10, int)
>>> G = reduce(np.kron, (A,B,I,I))
>>> H = reduce(np.kron, (I,A,I,B))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> (G.reshape(*8*(10,)).transpose(2,0,3,1,6,4,7,5).reshape(10**4,10**4) == H).all()
True
```

Explanation: Let's look at a minimal example to understand how the Kronecker product relates to reshaping and axis shuffling.

Two 1D factors:

```
>>> A, B = np.arange(1,5), np.array(list("abcd"), dtype=object)
>>> np.kron(A, B)
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',
       'ddd', 'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd'], dtype=object)
```

We can observe that the arrangement is row-major-ish, so if we reshape we actually get the outer product:

```
>>> np.kron(A, B).reshape(4, 4)
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
       ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'],
       ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd']], dtype=object)
>>> np.outer(A, B)
array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'],
       ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'],
       ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd']], dtype=object)
```

If we do the same with factors swapped we get the transpose:

```
>>> np.kron(B, A).reshape(4, 4)
array([['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa'],
       ['b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'bbbb'],
       ['c', 'cc', 'ccc', 'cccc'],
       ['d', 'dd', 'ddd', 'dddd']], dtype=object)
```

With 2D factors things are similar

```
>>> A2, B2 = A.reshape(2,2), B.reshape(2,2)
>>> 
>>> np.kron(A2, B2)
array([['a', 'b', 'aa', 'bb'],
       ['c', 'd', 'cc', 'dd'],
       ['aaa', 'bbb', 'aaaa', 'bbbb'],
       ['ccc', 'ddd', 'cccc', 'dddd']], dtype=object)
>>> np.kron(A2, B2).reshape(2,2,2,2)
array([[[['a', 'b'],
         ['aa', 'bb']],

        [['c', 'd'],
         ['cc', 'dd']]],


       [[['aaa', 'bbb'],
         ['aaaa', 'bbbb']],

        [['ccc', 'ddd'],
         ['cccc', 'dddd']]]], dtype=object)
```

But there is a minor complication in that the corresponding outer product has axes arranged differently:

```
>>> np.multiply.outer(A2, B2)
array([[[['a', 'b'],
         ['c', 'd']],

        [['aa', 'bb'],
         ['cc', 'dd']]],


       [[['aaa', 'bbb'],
         ['ccc', 'ddd']],

        [['aaaa', 'bbbb'],
         ['cccc', 'dddd']]]], dtype=object)
```

We need to swap middle axes to get the same result.

```
>>> np.multiply.outer(A2, B2).swapaxes(1,2)
array([[[['a', 'b'],
         ['aa', 'bb']],

        [['c', 'd'],
         ['cc', 'dd']]],


       [[['aaa', 'bbb'],
         ['aaaa', 'bbbb']],

        [['ccc', 'ddd'],
         ['cccc', 'dddd']]]], dtype=object)
```

So if we want to go the swapped Kronecker product we can swap the middle axes: (0,2,1,3)

now we have the outer product. swapping factors exchanges the first two axes with the second two: (1,3,0,2)

going back to Kronecker, swap the middle axes

=> total axis permutation: (1,0,3,2)

```
>>> np.all(np.kron(A2, B2).reshape(2,2,2,2).transpose(1,0,3,2).reshape(4,4) == np.kron(B2, A2))
True
```

Using the same principles leads to the recipe for the four factor original question.

Comment: This does seem to work, although why it should is pretty mysterious to me. Can you explain how you figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

This answer expands on Paul Panzer's correct answer to document how one would solve similar problems like this more generally.

Suppose we wish to map a matrix string `reduce(kron, ABCD)` into, for example, `reduce(kron, CADB)`, where each matrix has dimension `d` columns. Both of the strings are thus `d**4, d**4` matrices. Alternatively they are `[d,]*8` shaped arrays.

The way `np.kron` arranges data means that the index ordering of `ABDC` corresponds to that of its constituents as follows: `D_0 C_0 B_0 A_0 D_1 C_1 B_1 A_1` where for example `D_0` (`D_1`) is the fastest (slowest) oscillating index in `D`. For `CADB` the index ordering is instead (`B_0 D_0 A_0 C_0 B_1 D_1 A_1 C_1`); you just read the string backwards once for the faster and once for the slower indices. The appropriate permutation string in this case is thus `(2,0,3,1,6,4,7,5)`.